# Firebase onAuthStateChange return undefined when page refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, react-router

Firebase onAuthStateChange return the first result as undefined when I refresh page. Because of that I can not check if user is authenticated or not.

My useAuth hook:

```
export default function useAuth() {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState();

  const user = useFirebase();

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(user.auth, (user) => {
      user ? setAuthUser(user) : setAuthUser(false);
    });
  }, [user]);

  return authUser;
}
```

When I try to refresh page, first result of user is undefined, end then I get result.

[image]

```
function App() {
  const authUser = useAuth();

  console.log("au", authUser);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/blogs" element={<BlogsPage />} />
        <Route path="/blog/:id" element={<SingleBlogPage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
        <Route
          path="/admin"
          element={authUser ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate to="/vanja-login" />}
        >
          <Route exact path="dashboard" element={<Settings />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState();` There's always going to be a delay before the first onAuthStateChanged, and you've set your initial state to undefined. So the fact that you're seeing a render with undefined seems normal to me. Maybe you'll want to check for `undefined` and render a loading placeholder? When the auth state changes for real, it will either be an object or null, not undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial `authUser` state is undefined for the initial render so this is expected behavior. The `onAuthStateChanged` listener is instantiated at the end of the initial render cycle via the `useEffect`. If any part of your UI depends on this "indeterminant" `authUser` state it should handle it accordingly.

Additionally, you should also unsubscribe any auth status listeners when the component unmounts or the `user` object from firebase updates/changes.

Example:

```
export default function useAuth() {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState();

  const user = useFirebase();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      user.auth,
      (user) => setAuthUser(user ?? false)
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user]);

  return authUser;
}
```

...

```
const AuthLayout = () => {
  const authUser = useAuth();

  console.log("au", authUser);

  if (authUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return authUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/vanja-login" />;
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/blogs" element={<BlogsPage />} />
        <Route path="/blog/:id" element={<SingleBlogPage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
        <Route path="/admin" element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Settings />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```