# react router v6 always redirecting to home on refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, react-router

I've set up protected routes, firebase login functionality, and a redux store for the login state on my app and I've been trying to set the app up so I can refresh any page and it will stay on that page, but as of right now it will always redirect to my LandingPage component

This is my App.js component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { login, logout, selectUser } from '../features/userSlice';
import { auth, onAuthStateChanged } from '../firebase';
import ProtectedRoute from '../scrpits/ProtectedRoutes';
import { AuthProvider } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import { MainLayout } from '../scrpits/partials/MainLayout';
import { Home } from '../scrpits/Home';
import { LandingPage } from '../scrpits/LandingPage';
import { Profile } from '../scrpits/Profile';
import { Categories } from '../scrpits/Categories';
import { AddPage } from '../scrpits/AddPage';
import { ViewPage } from '../scrpits/ViewPage';
import '../styles/App.css';

const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        //logged in
        dispatch(
          login({
            email: userAuth.email,
            uid: userAuth.uid,
          })
        );
      } else {
        dispatch(logout());
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact strict path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
              <Route
                path="home"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <Home />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="profile"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <Profile />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="categories"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <Categories />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="addpage"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <AddPage />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="viewpage"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <ViewPage />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              ></Route>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the ProtectedRoute component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  console.log('Check user in Private: ', currentUser);
  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }
  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

This is the AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { login as loginUser } from '../features/userSlice';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function signup(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
      (userAuth) => {
        dispatch(
          loginUser({
            email: userAuth.email,
            uid: userAuth.uid,
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }

  function googleSignIn() {
    const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
  }

  function logout() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setCurrentUser(currentUser);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
    login,
    logout,
    googleSignIn,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

I've seen some solutions which use the useHistory hook but that isn't an option in react router v6 so I can't use that, and the useNavigate hook throws an error because I'm attempting to use it outside the BrowserRouter context.

Comment: Is it the `ProtectedRoute` component that is redirecting when the app/page loads? Can you include all relevant code you've an issue working with?

Comment: HI Drew, I've just added the ProtectedRoute and AuthContext code

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71530370/8690857 The gist is that `currentUser` is undefined on the initial render and the redirect happens before the `useEffect` hook can instantiate the firebase auth listener and update/validate the current user state. In other words, it incorrectly assumes no user is authenticated prior to the check occurring.

Comment: Drew! Thank you so much, I just had to make two tiny changes in my ProtectedRoutes component as you suggest in the linked page and it works perfectly, and I now have a little more understanding of what's going on thanks to your great explanation. You have no idea how happy you've made me. I've been tearing my hair out for 4 days trying to fix this issue